# how to encrypt a sensitive model on android and ios

Tags: encryption, android, ios

I am writing a mobile app which uses a statistical model contained in binary files. I want to be able to distribute the app freely, but I don't want anyone to be able to use my model files, even on a rooted device. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet would be to include in the EULA clauses about not reverse engineering the application.  Checkout [section 1.5](https://www.infuzer.com/IDC/register/eula.jsp).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest storing the model on server, and then having the app Query the server with input to the model, and getting response back.
If you dont want competitors to be able to use your server as the model itself, I would suggest requiring users to register, and then imposing a limit on how many model queries that can be done per second or per minute, so a competitor cannot just hardcode one account in their app.

Basically, lets say you have a statistical model over how many people die per year given the population as input.
Then you give the population as input to the server (can be a simple HTTP GET), and get the number of people who die per year, as output.

This also allows you to combine different models in ways to impose restrictions on how your model may be used. You can also put restrictions on maximum and minimum inputs in integers.
For example: giving the imput of Power and frequency, you get some value, that, still on server side, is fed into a Another model giving this value and degrees as input, gives a output value.
In that case, you have inputs: Power, frequency, degrees. and then a single output, from 2 models.

If you make the models and logic on server side so complicated it cannot be deduced by trial and error, you have a watertight solution. If you someday decide to start collecting Money for this service, you can ensure that only paying users have access to the service of calculating the model, and you can even debet a pay-per-calculation model where the user has to pay for each input done to the model.

Also make sure your model is not alright so simple as it could be mathimatically be reconstructed by feeding specifically constructed inputs to the model. Then EULA cannot prevent it either, since the end user could simply feed in inputs in the application and get results back, so many times so the model could be reconstructed "outside of box" and that would not Count as reverse engiinering.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing today. The problem is that the calculation is pretty intensive so I thought I can use the device's CPU instead of the server.The model is complicated, reverse engineering it is not a concern.

Comment: If the calculation is based on mathimatical primitives, you can use Homorphic encryption, so the model stays encrypted on client. Eg: Client sends input to server. Client gets encrypted input back. Client puts encrypted input through encrypted model, and gets encrypted output back. Client sends encrypted output to server and gets plaintext output. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, no... in more details... you will have to give the "app" some way of using the model. which means that ALL methods of encryption require you giving the "app" the keys to the encrypted content. even sending it to the app over the Internet does the same. so basicly all you can do is making it not so easy to get the model. but flat out prevention is impossible.

@sebastian, this solution is not going to hold for long. since you need to "allow" the client access (which means the reverse engineer has the access). and "complexity" is often just not there. (almost all complexity is either given or hinted at by the app itself. only features not present in any way in the app, can be "obscured" from the engineer. provided there not obvious and are complex on there own.

Comment: Can't I distribute the app without the model, download it and some encryption key from the server, save the files encrypted and ask the server for the key each time?

Comment: than as a reverse engineer can also decrypt your file.

Comment: How? (If I use a long key and keep it in memory only)

Comment: because I have hardware access, I can READ the memory (for example). the key length is not important because I can just READ the key. and, you have to DELIVER the key to your app in some way, i can Sniff out that communication. (or use a SSL-stripper to intercept it in clear text on the line), its just not something you can truly defend yourself against. you can only make it "not so easy" to get the model or use legal methods to restrict use. but to flat out prevent it. its not possible.

Comment: Think about how smart cards work. You provide a input, and get a output, but you never get to see "inside" the black box. That how a client-server model in this scheme would work. Thats also the reason to impose limits on both inputs and the rate of requests, to avoid that a attacker "bruteforces" through all inputs and gets all available outputs, and the reconstruct the model outside of server.